# Cannot upload image Cloudinary - Android

Tags: android, image, upload, cloudinary

I cannot upload a image of Android to Cloudinary, i dont know why, error when try to uploader. Dont make any message only Method threw 'java.io.IOException' exception.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
          Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imageBitmap);  
            InputStream in = null;    
            try {
                in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            Map config = new HashMap();
            config.put("cloud_name", "...");
            config.put("api_key", "...");
            config.put("api_secret", "...");
            Cloudinary mobileCloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);    
            try {
                mobileCloudinary.uploader().upload(in, ObjectUtils.asMap("public_id", "sample_remote"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: post your error stack

Comment: dont make error, only dont upload the image

Comment: the error is in your last try catch block, that line is throwing that error

Comment: try to debug, and check the values of all the variables before upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload call requires server communication. Android doesn't allow it to happen on the main (UI) thread. 
You can try to wrap the upload call with an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). That way, the upload call takes place on a different thread, not disturbing the UI.

A (very) simple example of such wrap -

```
class CloudinaryUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            Map imageResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload("file", ObjectUtils.emptyMap());

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
          //do something with imageResult
    }
}
```